# Nativescript-Vue Remove iOS ListView tap color

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

How can you change the tap color on a list item? My app is a dark theme so when you click the cell has a white flash which is pretty ugly. I have tried the following:

component

```
const ls  = this.$refs.list

ls.itemLoading=(args)=>{
  const cell = args.ios;
  cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

}
```

I have also tried that in my `mounted` method on a component that has a ListView

`this.$refs.list` logs:

```
 _uid: 20,
_isVue: true,
'$options':
{ parent:
{ _uid: 19,
_isVue: true,
'$options': [Object],
_renderProxy: [Object],
_self: [Circular],
'$parent': [Object],
'$root': [Object],
'$children': [Object],
'$refs': [Object],
_watcher: [Object],
_inactive: null,
_directInactive: false,
_isMounted: true,
_isDestroyed: false,
_isBeingDestroyed: false,
_events: [Object],
_hasHookEvent: false,
_vnode: [Object],
_staticTrees: null,
'$vnode': [Object],
'$slots': {},
'$scopedSlots': {},
_c: [Object],
'$createElement': [Object],
'$attrs': [Getter/Setter],
'$listeners': [Getter/Setter],
'$store': [Object],
_watchers: [Object],
_props: [Object],
clearHistory: [Object],
go: [Object],
_data: [Object],
clubs: [<…>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use event binding for `itemLoading`

HTML

```
<ListView ref="listview" @itemLoading="onItemLoading">
```

JS

```
onItemLoading: function(args) {
   const cell = args.ios;
   if (cell) {
     cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
   }
}
```

Comment: Is there that event though on ListView Nativescript-Vue?? In the Docs it only has the event of itemTap:  https://nativescript-vue.org/en/docs/elements/components/list-view/

Comment: You can see all the list of events in the official [ListView docs](https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/classes/_ui_list_view_.listview) and follow the appropriate syntax for your framework.

Comment: But are those all exposed as events on a ListView vue component?

Comment: Yes, obviously. All the core events / apis are applicable for Vue. NativeScript-Vue is just a wrapper around the Core components that makes it easy for Vue developers to reuse their knowledge and the fancy framework features.

Comment: Thanks! It wasnt obvious to me since I was just looking at the nativescript-vue.org docs that only had a Tap event listed.

Comment: Sorry about that, hope you are good now. Happy coding with {N} Vue.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks good. However, you're just slightly off.

You're referencing the `listview` module via your require. You need to use the event on an instance of a `ListView` and not the module.

So in a page event or vue lifecycle event for a page/component you should get the instance of your `ListView` from your template and then use the `itemLoading` event just as you have it.

Comment: I tried add a `ref` to to the `ListView` and in `mounted` I did `this.$refs.list.itemLoading=(args) ...` but no luck

Comment: can you actually log out the instance of `list` to confirm it's a `ListView` ?

Comment: I just updated the question with what `<ListView ref="listview">` returns

Comment: Would it be `this.$refs.list.nativeView` for the `ListView`? I don't know Vue, so I'm not sure, just seen that before with other questions.